# How to implement events for the controls which are programmatically added in the view?

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin.mac

I am working on cocoa application for OSX in Xamarin in which i am adding controls like buttons, Shapes etc programmatically to the Sub View. I know how to add click events during the design design time. Is there any way to implement the events (click etc) for the controls which are programmatically added in the view ?

Comment: This may be totally ignorant, but can you do `Btn1.click += Btn1_click;` where `Btn1_click` is the handler?

Comment: @SimpleStudent : This code is applicable for .NET. I am working on xamarin studio for developing mac cocoa app in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the activated event:

```
Btn1.Activated += Btn1_Activated;
```

or

```
Btn1.Activated += (sender, e) => {
        // code here
    };
```